# Make directory below working python

Tags: python, permissions, operating-system

When I am trying to `os.makedirs("/home/user/newdir")`, while python script is located "/home/user/somefolder" it gives me 
`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user'`
So how can I make `newdir`

Comment: Are you sure the `/home/user` directory already exists?  I believe that error indicates that the effective user that python is running as does not have permission to create the `/home/user` directory (which `os.makedirs` has to create before creating the `/home/user/newdir directory`), so it's puzzling to me that you say it already exists.

Comment: In any case, you need to either change the effective user that python is running as so your script does have permission, or you need to change the permission settings for the folder `/home`.

Comment: Ohh, geee... I used socket.gethostname() to get the /home/<user>/... and the <user> is wrong, I guess that explains a lot.

Comment: @KristiansKuhta for resolving `~/...` see [`os.path.expanduser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Comment: @Kristians: don't put "solved" or any other marker like that in your title. If you've found a solution to your problem, post an answer yourself (you can even accept it to mark this post as answered).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I used `socket.gethostname()` to get the user name of my pc, but I should have used `getpass.getuser()` instead. The `getpass.gethostname()` gave me "chriss", while in kristians@chriss:~$